# SmartWatch sample installation

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I would like to compile the sample provided by Sony for his SmartWatch. I followed the instructions in this [page](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/05/07/music-player-and-8-game-extensions-for-smartwatch-now-available-as-open-source/). But when I added the the `SmartExtensionUtils` project I saw lot of errors like: `com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef cannot be resolved to a variable`. Instead this import `com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware` has no problem.
Did someone find and solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

In order for the EightPuzzleGame to compile, you need to add the following library projects that are available in the SDK:

- SmartExtensionAPI
- SmartExtensionUtils
- SmartExtensionInternalUtils

In your case, it is the API project that is probably missing. You can see what library projects that are missing by checking the project properties. Example:

[image: Project properties]

Comment: The following one is a link to my desktop screenshot. SmartExtensionAPI and utils are in the project list (left side) but the EightPuzzleExtension does not find them

![Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1676892/Capture.PNG)

Comment: Now I'm able to compile SEAPI and SEUtils but the two samples by sony do not comile yet. I have problems with R.java file. Some method of the R class do not exist.

Then I cannot find SmartExtensionInternalUtils project in the SDK. Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is go to the properties page of the SmartExtensionUtils library and in the library box add SmartExtensionAPI as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

This is a [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1676892/Capture.PNG) to my desktop screenshot. SmartExtensionAPI and utils are in the project list (left side) but the EightPuzzleExtension does not find them

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SmartExtensionInternalUtils project. When you create project from existing source, check Import project into Workspace. In this way EightPuzzle, SEAPI and SEUtils will be in the same directory and you'll not have no errors :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. What i did is to solve it, is to import from the Sony samples in the Sony add-on SDK 3.0 the SmartExtensionAPI first and than SmartExtensionUtils. If these samples are build correctly the other samples will build correctly as well.

Go to File|Import, choose SmartExtensionAPI as your root directory and click finish. Maybe you have to change the compiler compliance level to build it correctly. After this do the same for SmartExtensionUtils.