# getting started making sony smartwatch app

Tags: android, eclipse, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am currently trying to make a simple sony smartwatch app to get familiar with it, however, even using the Sony Add-on SDK examples it gives me errors right away, for example in the SampleNotificationExtension it says

> com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.util cannot be resolved

and in another example code it says

> "com.sonyericsson" cannot be resolved

I have the newest ADT and Eclipse but when the sony add-on SDK example code doesn't work I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a couple of library projects to your own project. These are available in the SDK.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537699/smartwatch-sample-installation/16544518#16544518) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Download the new [Smart Extension SDK](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/smart-extras-accessories/) and add it :)

You can find them in Code_examples, add these, Project > new > Android > Android from existing project.

> SmartExtensionAPI
>
> SmartExtensionUtils

After that right click EightPuzzle.... > properties > Android > Select Sony Add-On SDK
Remove the ones with the red X, click Add, select SmartExtensionAPI Needed for your project