# Sony Smartwatch samples - second step

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I still trying to compile the two samples code from sony: EightPuzzleExtension and MusicPreferenceActivity. These are the steps I did:
1. I installed the sony add-on from the Android SDK Manager as explained [here](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sdks/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/)
2. I imported the sample projects following the instructions [here](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/05/07/music-player-and-8-game-extensions-for-smartwatch-now-available-as-open-source/)
3. I added the Project references SmartExtensionAPI in the SmartExtensionUtils. **Now both SmartExtensionAPI and SmartExtensionUtils compile**.
4. I added the Project references SmartExtensionAPI and SmartExtensionUtils to the sample projects. But they do not compile yet. Lots of error are solved (this is the first step) but there are still errors related to R class.

I already saw [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537699/smartwatch-sample-installation/16544518) but it is not useful because I cannot find the SmartExtensionInternalUtils. Where they are? How can I get them?

thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting in the R class?

Comment: You dont need the SmartExtensionInternalUtils. R.java related errors are usually because some error in a XML file. What API version are you building to? Have a look in the XML files for a error.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF file from Sony Developer website says :
"Widgets can’t be used in SmartWatch 2 currently. It is recommended that an extension does not
register itself as using the Widget API when registering to SmartWatch 2."

Widgets are only supported with SDK 1.0 and the Music player is designed for 1.0.
Only have errors on MusicWidgetExtension.java file no ?