# The import com.sonymobile cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, adt, importerror, sony

I'm trying to build an Android project that depends on Sony Add-on SDK, so I installed Sony Add-on SDK 3.0 for Android 4.4.2 (API19):

[image]

The project's .properties is set to target API19:

```
# Project target.
target=android-19
```

But I still get an error on this line, saying it can't find com.sonymobile:

```
import com.sonymobile.camera.addon.capturingmode.CapturingModeSelector;
```

The error text is:

> The import com.sonymobile cannot be resolved

But I have installed Sony Add-on SDK 3.0 for the correct API version, so what gives?

Comment: Have you added the Add-on SDK as dependency to your project?

Comment: Can you explain a bit? I'm doing C++ mainly, so I'm not very familiar with ADT or eclipse. Btw the project is not created by me, I'm trying to set it up on my computer, so if it's a project setting I'm assuming they would have already done that. Or is it just an Eclipse setting that's local to the computer?

Comment: Ok, so you maybe have downloaded the SDK but maybe it isn't already added to your project so your IDE doesn't know that the SDK exists. I have to admit I haven't worked with Eclipse in a long time now so I can't give you further instructions on how to add the SDK. This might help you a little bit more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537699/smartwatch-sample-installation/16544518#16544518

Comment: Thanks, the link helped, and it's working now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @Thorben suggested, I needed to [change the build target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537699/smartwatch-sample-installation/16544518#16544518) from Android 4.4.2 to Sony Add-on SDK 3.0 (in Context Menu->Properties->Android):

[image]